# printing the wins and losses for each roll

Tags: c++, arrays

I am learning C++ right now and I am kinda confused about how to . I am programming the gambling game CRAPS and I want the output to be like the number of games that are won and lost on the 1st roll, 2nd roll, etc

```
____ games won and ____ games lost on roll 
____ games won and ____ games lost on roll
```

I am just lost on how to get each count for win and lost after each roll.

I tried including arrays for each time the die are rolled, but it says there's an error of:

```
invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
++wins[roll];
```

I do not understand what the error means. Can someone help a newbie out? Just need some hints :)

Here is my code so far and what I think I need to change:

```
unsigned int rollDice();
int wins;
int loses;
int winSum = 0;
int loseSum = 0;
int roll;

int main(){
  enum class Status {CONTINUE, WON, LOST};
  srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

  unsigned int myPoint{0};
  Status gameStatus;
  unsigned int sumOfDice{rollDice()};

  for (int i = 1; i <=1000; i++){
    sumOfDice = rollDice();
    roll = 1;

    while(Status::CONTINUE == gameStatus){
      sumOfDice = rollDice();
      ++roll;

      if (sumOfDice == myPoint){
        gameStatus = Status::WON;
      }else if(sumOfDice == 7){
        gameStatus = Status::LOST;
      }
    }

    if(roll > 21){
      roll = 21;
    }

    if (Status::WON == gameStatus){
      ++wins[roll]; //maybe has smt to do w this one
      winSum++;
    }else{
      ++loses[roll]; //maybe has smt to do w this one
      loseSum++;
    }
  }
  int totalGame = winSum + loseSum;
  int length = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i <= 21; i++){
    if(i == 21){
      cout << wins[i] << " games won and " << loses[i]
         << " games lost on rolls after 20th roll" << endl;
         //maybe has smt to do w this one
    }else{
      cout << wins[i] << " games won and " << loses[i]
         << " games lost on roll " << i <<endl;
         //maybe has smt to do w this one
    }
  }
  cout << winSum << "\n"<<endl;
  cout << loseSum;

}

unsigned int rollDice() {
  int die1{1 + rand()%6};
  int die2{1 + rand()%6};
  int sum{die1+die2};

  return sum;
}
```

Again, tysm for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to pay close attention to your types.

You have declared the variables `wins` and `loses` as type `int` on lines 2 and 3, however you are trying to use them like an int array where you do `++wins[roll]` and `++loses[roll]`. So you did correctly identify what lines the problem was on, but not what the problem is.

You will have to change the declaration of `wins` and `loses` to be an array, but also an array that is large enough to hold all the possible values of the dice rolls. Since the dice roll maximum is 12, you should declare `wins` and `loses` as follows:

```
int wins[13];
int loses[13];
```

The reason it is 13 and not 12 is because since arrays start at 0, if you want to be able to store an int at position 12, the array needs to be 13 elements long (0 - 12).